# WCF: parameters handled in custom channel not present in generated WSDL

Tags: wcf, soap

I have some special parameters to all my wcf service methods that are handled inside a custom channel and are not exposed in the service method parameter list.  This works fine for json/xml endpoints, but the I don't know how to use a SOAP endpoint with this setup because the generated WSDL doesn't include fields that are not in the service call parameter list.

Is there a way I can centralize the handling of the special parameters that apply to all service methods (authentication, locale and other contextual information) and provide a SOAP endpoint that Just Works (tm)?

Hand editing wsdl files is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide something that implements [IWsdlExportExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx) to modify the WSDL as it is generated to contain the extra information you want. (Your custom channel BindingElement might be a good place to do this).